# How do I define an operator to be a macro?

Tags: macros, elixir, operator-overloading

Basically I'm trying to do this:

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro a <~ b do
    quote do
      case unquote(a) do
        ^unquote(b) -> true
        _ -> false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The functionality of this macro is to check if the pattern match, and returns true if it does.

When I'm trying this out in IEX:

```
> // codes above
warning: redefining module A (current version defined in memory)
  iex:23

{:module, A,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 5, 232, 66, 69, 65, 77, 65, 116, 85, 56, 0, 0, 0, 181,
   0, 0, 0, 21, 8, 69, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 46, 65, 8, 95, 95, 105, 110,
   102, 111, 95, 95, 10, 97, 116, 116, 114, ...>>, {:<~, 2}}
> require A
A
> 1 <~ 1
** (CompileError) iex:26: undefined function <~/2 (there is no such import)
    (elixir 1.14.0) src/elixir.erl:364: :elixir.quoted_to_erl/3
    (elixir 1.14.0) src/elixir.erl:274: :elixir.eval_forms/3
    (elixir 1.14.0) lib/module/parallel_checker.ex:100: Module.ParallelChecker.verify/1
    (iex 1.14.0) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:329: IEx.Evaluator.eval_and_inspect/3
    (iex 1.14.0) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:303: IEx.Evaluator.eval_and_inspect_parsed/3
    (iex 1.14.0) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:292: IEx.Evaluator.parse_eval_inspect/3
    (iex 1.14.0) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:187: IEx.Evaluator.loop/1
```

Answer (score 0):

`require` does not import the functions in the module into the current scope. For that, you need to do `import A`.

Also, if I understand the question correctly, you don't need the `^` before `unquote(b)` if `b` is supposed to be a pattern.

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro a <~ b do
    quote do
      case unquote(a) do
        unquote(b) -> true
        _ -> false
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Main do
  def main do
    import A
    IO.inspect({:ok, 1} <~ {:ok, _})
    IO.inspect({:ok, 1} <~ {:ok, 2})
  end
end

Main.main()
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

---

Also note that there exists `Kernel.match?/2` macro which does the same thing, but with arguments flipped:

```
  defmacro a <~ b do
    quote do
      match?(unquote(b), unquote(a))
    end
  end
```